# I want to find LCM of two numbers but I am getting recursion error.Where am I going wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

The below code gives me infinite recursion error!

```
count1 = 1
def lcm(a,b):
    global count1
    if a%2==0 and b%2==0:
        count1*=2
        return lcm(a%2,b%2)

    elif a%3==0 and b%3==0:
        count1*=3
        return lcm(a%3,b%3)

    else:
        return count1*a*b

print(lcm(12,24))
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first iteration, `a%2` does equal zero (12 % 2) and so does `b%2` (24 % 2).

Now you have doubled `count1`. And then you call `lcm` with parameters `(0, 0)` (because as already established, `12 % 2 == 0 and 24 % 2 == 0`).

Next we are doing `0 % 2` which equals `0`. And then the cycle continues forever.

Code for better solution:

```
def gcd(x, y):
   # This is the Euclidian algorithm for getting the highest
   # common factor (greatest common denominator) of two numbers
   while y != 0:
       x, y = y, x % y
   return x

def lcm(x, y):
   lcm = (x*y)//gcd(x,y)
   return lcm


print(lcm(12, 24))
```

[Source](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/lcm)

Comment: wow!Glad to know I can also find out LCM without using GCF.Thanks for the source!

Comment: Yep I was passing LCM(0,0) and hence it was looping forever.Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear *how* you're going about implementing `lcm`, but my understanding is

```
# lowest common multiple
# where gcd = greatest common divisor
lcm(m,n) = m * n / gcd(m,n)
```

with that, we can implement `lcm` quite easily

```
def gcd (m,n):
  if n == 0:
    return m
  else:
    return gcd(n, m % n)

def lcm (m,n):
  return m * n / gcd(m,n)

print(lcm(12,24)) # 24
```